# Drop down navigation with changing order

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am trying to create a drop-down navigation bar with 2 rows. **By default, only 1 row is shown**. If you click this row, both rows should show. Then, if you click one of the 2 rows, only that row should show. And so on. Here is few images which should demonstrate what I wish to achieve.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, but I wish to do it without jQuery. https://codepen.io/matthewbeta/pen/zioHr

[image] [image] [image]

It partially already works, but I cannot figure out how to show Row-B only when it's clicked. Now what happens is, you click Row-A, both rows are shown. If you click Row-B, Row-A shows only.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var rowB = document.getElementById("rowB");
rowB.style.display = "none";

select.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (rowB.style.display == "none") {
    rowB.style.display = "flex";
  }
  else {rowB.style.display = "none"};
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 70px 160px 70px;
}

#select {
  width: 270px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 2;
}

#rowA,
#rowB {
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  border: #2e2e2e 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="select">
      <div id="rowA">Row-A</div>
      <div id="rowB">Row-B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few modification on the js part only:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var rowB = document.getElementById("rowB");
rowB.style.display = "none";

select.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(event.target.id === 'rowA') {
    rowB.style.display = (rowB.style.display === 'none')? "block" : "none";
    rowB.style.order = '1';
    rowA.style.order = '0';
  }
  else if(event.target.id === 'rowB') {
    rowA.style.display = (rowA.style.display === 'none')? "block" : "none";
    rowA.style.order = '1';
    rowB.style.order = '0';
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 70px 160px 70px;
}

#select {
  width: 270px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 2;
}

#rowA,
#rowB {
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  border: #2e2e2e 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="select">
      <div id="rowA">Row-A</div>
      <div id="rowB">Row-B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is when you open rowB, you cannot continue anymore to rowA.

Comment: Thank you, its better. I managed to achieve this before, but my problem is, I would like the order to change as well. So when you click rowB, it shouldnt jump to the bottom, just doesn't look professional to me.

Comment: Edited again, check it now.

Comment: Hey, this is great. Thank you very much!